# VBA automatically agree to enable macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that is opening a lot of different excel files with macros. However, every time VBA opens a file, it says "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern", and I have to select "Enable Macros". Is there a way to add a line, that would always choose "Enable Macros", as I cannot change any excel settings (it is a corporate computer, without admin rights)?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You should be able to update `Trust Center` settings without admin rights which is what you would need to do here. You can either set all macro-enabled files to open (not generally recommended) or if possible set up a `Trusted Location` where any files opened within that area are marked as trusted, so wouldn't trigger this message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I am developing this for firm-wide level, so the location differs from person to person. Is there no way for VBA to select "enable" by themselves?

Comment: How do you run a VBA line when macros are disabled? If it is running from a master file then wrapping your file handling with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False/True` may work. Otherwise here may be an answer: [Skip 'Enable Macros' Dialogue box when Opening a File with VBA](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/skip-enable-macros-dialogue-box-when-opening-a-file-with-vba.920110/)

Answer (score 1):

Typically when opening a macro-enabled file using code, there's no security prompt. It would help to show the code you're using to open the files.

However if you do see a prompt you can fix that by setting `Application.AutomationSecurity` to the appropriate value

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity